# EF Core error : "No suitable constructor was found for entity type..."

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a database via Entity Framework Core.

I have the following models in my 'Domain' project:

```
public abstract class Note
{
    protected Note(string mainBody, DateTime publicationMoment, User author)
    {
        MainBody = mainBody;
        PublicationMoment = publicationMoment;
        AuthorId = author.Id;
        Author = author;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(1500)]
    public virtual string MainBody { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [NoteDateTime]
    public DateTime PublicationMoment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public User Author { get; set; }
}

public class Comment : Note
{
    public Comment(Post post, string mainBody, DateTime publicationMoment, User author) : 
        base(mainBody, publicationMoment, author)
    {
        Post = post;
        PostId = post.Id;
    }

    [Required]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}

public class Post : Note
{
    public Post(string title, string mainBody, DateTime publicationMoment, User author) : 
        base(mainBody, publicationMoment, author) => Title = title;
    
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new List<Comment>();
}

public class User
{
    public User(string nickname, int age, Gender gender)
    {
        Nickname = nickname;
        Age = age;
        Gender = gender;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Nickname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(14, 130)]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}
```

And the BlogContext class inside my 'Infrastructure' project:

```
public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users => Set<User>();
    public DbSet<Post> Posts => Set<Post>();
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments => Set<Comment>();

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        var config = builder.Build();

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("Default"));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasAlternateKey(u => u.Nickname);
    } 
}
```

When I'm trying to add my first migration in Package Manager Console (like so: `Add-Migration BlogDbCreation`, I'm getting the following error:

"No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Comment'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type:
Cannot bind 'post', 'author' in 'Comment(Post post, string mainBody, DateTime publicationMoment, User author)'
Note that only mapped properties can be bound to constructor parameters. Navigations to related entities, including references to owned types, cannot be bound."

So, how can I solve it?

Comment: It basically tells you: "Navigations to related entities, including references to owned types, cannot be bound." You need to provide  EF wit a constructor that does not include navigation properties.  The reason for this is that EF does not, nor should you want it to, eager load every navigation property when you retrieve an entity. Personally I use an internal one for factory methods to use with all of the properties/required navigations, and an empty protected one for EF.

Comment: @Steve, Thank you! So, I don't have to pass navigation properties inside my constructor, I got it. What about ```[Required]``` attribute? Should my navigation properties have them? If they do, doesn't it mean that I have to pass them through constructor?

Comment: [Required] is used for validation calls which is honestly something that is more of a view/ViewModel concern. I don't recommend passing entities to view to serve as view models as an entity should only be concerned with data state, where a ViewModel class can be responsible for view state. The fact that something like a Post navigation property is not null-able will ensure that EF treats it as required, though actually exceptions for violating that may only come up during SaveChanges.  The ViewModel can ensure any user modifications are complete for the code to update entity state after.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass the id:s in the constructors instead of the reference types and let EF do the mapping for you.
2. Have you considered dropping the 'Note' inheritance in favor of a strictly one-to-many relationship between Post and Comment?

   ```
   public abstract class Entity
   {
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
   }

   public class Comment : Entity
   {
     private Comment() { }
     public Comment(string mainBody, DateTime publicationMoment, Guid authorId)
       {
         MainBody = mainBody;
         PublicationMoment = publicationMoment;
         AuthorId = authorId;
       }
     public Post Post { get; set; } = null!;
     public string MainBody { get; set; }
     public DateTime PublicationMoment { get; set; }
     public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
     public User Author { get; set; } = null!;
   }

   public class Post : Entity
   {
     private Post() { }
     public Post(string title, string mainBody, DateTime publicationMoment, Guid authorId)
      {
        Title = title;
        MainBody = mainBody;
        PublicationMoment = publicationMoment;
        AuthorId = authorId;
      }

     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string MainBody { get; set; }
     public DateTime PublicationMoment { get; set; }
     public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
     public User Author { get; set; } = null!;
     public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new List<Comment>();
   }

    public class User : Entity
    {
      private User() { }
      public User(string nickname, int age)
        {
          Nickname = nickname;
          Age = age;
        }
     public string Nickname { get; set; } = null!;
     public int Age { get; set; }
    }
   ```